# Change collation for Spring Reactive MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using `spring-data-mongodb:2.2.2.RELEASE`, `spring-boot-starter-webflux:2.2.2.RELEASE` and a `Mongodb v4.2.x`. I need change the database collation in order to set it for being case insensitive for all queries.

I check the doc:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Collation.html
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.2.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#mongo.collation

but I don't figure out how use it with reactive templates.

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories
class MongoConfig {

// How should I use it?

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Since version 3.4, MongoDB supports collations for **collection** and **index creation** and various **query operations**.

Any of this solution:

- Modify your `@Document` entity to specify [collation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/mapping/Document.html#collation--)
- Modify your `@Repositories` with `@Query` (Example 82. Collation support for Repositories)
- Find, Aggregation, etc...

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.2.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#mongo.collation